# Can an MPI_WAITALL call be skipped if all requests are already complete?

Tags: fortran, mpi

Let's say I have an array of non-blocking `MPI` requests initiated in a series of calls to `MPI_ISEND` (or `MPI_IRECV`).  I store the request info in the array `xfer_rqst`.  It is my understanding that when a request completes, its corresponding value in `xfer_rqst` will be set to `MPI_REQUEST_NULL`.  Further, it's my understanding that if a call is made to MPI_WAITALL, it will have work to do only if some requests in `xfer_rqst` still have some value other than `MPI_REQUEST_NULL`.  If I have it right, then, if all requests complete before we get to the `MPI_WAITALL` call, then `MPI_WAITALL` will be a no-op for all intents and purposes.  If I am right about all this (hoo boy), then the following Fortran code should work and maybe occasionally save a useless function call:

```
IF (ANY(xfer_rqst /= MPI_REQUEST_NULL))       &
            CALL MPI_WAITALL(num_xfers, xfer_rqst, xfer_stat, ierr)
```

I have actually run this several times without an issue.  But still I wonder, is this code proper and safe?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is indeed often the case that you can decide from the structure of your code that certain requests are satisfied. So you think you can skip the wait call.

And indeed you often can in the sense that your code will work. The only thing you're missing is that the wait call deallocates your request object. In other words, by skipping the wait call you have created a memory leak. If your wait call is in a region that gets iterated many times, this is a problem. (As noted in the comments, the standard actually states that the wait call is needed to guarantee completion.)

In your particular case, I think you're wrong about the null request: it's the wait call that sets the request to null. Try it: see if any requests are null *before* the wait call.

Comment: OK, that I did not know.  Thanks!

Comment: I would put it more strongly. Quoting from  section 3.7 of the MPI 4.0 standard : "A nonblocking send start call initiates the send operation, but does not complete it.
The send start call can return before the message was copied out of the send buffer. A
separate send complete call is **needed** to complete the communication, i.e., to verify that the data has been copied out of the send buffer." (Emphasis mine). I read this as for every isend you *must* have a corresponding wait for the code to be standard compliant. There is equivalent language for recvs slightly later.

Comment: @IanBush True. But in practice you often have the case that after you wait for the receives, you know that the sends have to have been done, so a wait for them is not needed. Hm. I wonder if that code is not standard-compliant: `isend; irecv; wait for recv; wait for send`. Should that be `isend; irecv; waitall(2)` in order to be stancompl?

Comment: I think you have to wait on both. Why must the local recvs have completed just because the local sends have? I can't see at all why that is guaranteed. And anyway if you want to be practical it is is such a minor overhead for peace of mind why not do it?

Comment: @IanBush other way around: if the recvs are finished, the sends have to have finished.

Comment: Why? You have recv'ed the data from some remote node, that doesn't mean you have finished sending the data to a (possibly different) remote node.

Comment: @IanBush Ok, I'll spell it out. If every process does sends and receives, and every process finishes the receives, then the sends also have to be finished. No matter who I'm sending to, I know that the other process has finished its receives. Hey, I'm not saying that this is good let alone legal MPI, but I see it used regularly.

Comment: OK SO is complaining, so last thing I will say. Yes, globally once *all* the recvs across the *whole machine* are finished logically the sends must have done. But locally this is not the case. Just because your *local* recvs have finished doesn't mean you *local* sends have finished; your recv from proc 2 might be done, but that says nothing about your send to proc 4 at this instant. And mpi_wait only tests on the local sends and recvs, not the global state of the program.